# Django documentation reference

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am quite new to Django and I really don't get the documentation. For example in my code I query all available pages with `Page.objects.public()`. This gives me objects of type `cms.models.pagemodel.Page`. To use this in a template I need to know which methods I can use on this but I just cannot find the documentation and I cannot believe that I have to browse the Django source code to get to know the interface.

So does anyone know where I can find the available methods?

Comment: In Python you can always use `dir()` on an object to find out its attributes and methods. I'll be surprised if it's not documented though

Comment: Have you looked at the [models documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/)?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I have, it is not mentioned there.

Comment: I think you should be looking at the Django-CMS documentation, which defines that model, not the Django one.

Answer (score 2):

The [Django model instance reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/) has some helpful stuff, but generally when working with model instances, we tend to access their data as attributes (which will be in the model definition) and we call the `save` method after updating these attributes.

The data types you'll get back from Django model instance attributes are all going to be Python objects, so it's usually more important to understand how to interact with those than to understand all the methods available on an instance.

To get to know a Django model, you should look at its definition. Here's an example:

```
class Page(models.model):
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

For example, here, if you had a `Page` object with a `publication_date`, and that attribute was stored as a `DateTimeField`, then Django is going to give you a `datetime` object when you do:

```
>>> page = Page.objects.first()
>>> pubdate = page.publication_date 
>>> type(pubdate)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Similarly, the `name` attribute is simply a Python string:

```
>>> page.name = "New page name"
>>> page.save()
# New page name is stored in the db and will be there when queried next.
```

Lastly, to output these things in a template, you would just refer to them in the same way:

```
Assuming you have a `page` variable here that is an instance...
Page Name is: {{ page.name }}
```

The [Django book](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) may be more helpful to familiarize yourself with interacting with Django models.

Comment: _To get to know a Django model, you should look at its definition_
So I need to go through the Django source code? It is not an object of my code but from the Django CMS and the documentation does not mention it anywhere

Comment: @MichelH., not that "Django CMS" is _not_ Django. It is a separate [CMS built _with_ Django](http://www.django-cms.org/en/), but not part of the Django project. It has completely different developers, and [its own documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/). Since its models aren't part of Django, it is not surprising that they aren't documented there.

Comment: @Chris Ah, ok, that explains it although I can't find it in their documentation as well. I really thought those two belonged together. Thanks!